# Как при клике добавить элемент списка, при втором клике удалить тот самый элемент из списка?

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста как при клике добавить элемент списка, при втором клике удалить тот самый элемент из списка. Пробывал по id добвлять и удалять, не получается, remove() удаляет все элементы, remove() first() last() не подходит, нужно удалять тот самый элемент который был нажат и добавлен с номером телефона. Заране спасибо.

```js
//result search click
$(document).on('click', '.search-number__result', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('result-click');
  if ($(this).hasClass('result-click')) {
    let numberTel = $(this).find('.search-number__tel').text();
    $('.data-list').append(`<li class="selected-numbers__item" data-tel='${this.id}'>${numberTel}</li>`);
  } else {
    $(".data-list li").find(`[data-tel='${this.id}']`).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.search-number__result {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
  max-width: 230px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.result-click {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-number__box results-box">
  <div class="search-number__title">
  </div>
  <div class="search-number__wrap">
    <div class="search-number__result" id="0">
      <div class="search-number__flag">
        <img src="" alt="Flag" class="img-fluid"></div>
      <div class="search-number__content"><span class="search-number__tel">+19895752321</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--footer results-->
  <div class="search-footer row">
    <div class="search-footer__box col">
      <ol class="data-list p-0 mt-2 mb-0" id="selected-num"></ol>
    </div>
    <div class="search-footer__button col-12 col-sm-auto">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну запишите значение `id` в какой-нибудь `data` аттрибут, например `data-id`  и по этому аттрибуту ищите в `.data-list`. Если там это есть то удаляйте, если нет то добавьте новый элемент с этим `data` аттрибутом и нужным вам содержимым

Comment: @EzioMercer у него так и написано, только поиск по дата атрибуту не работает. Надо формировать id и работать с ним, jquery динамически добавленныне data-атрибуту в DOM не вносит, по ним поиск работать не будет. Надо тогда явно вписывать как `attr('data-..` но тту смысла нет.

Comment: @teran Не понял, если честно. Почему с помощью jQuery я не могу создать элемент с нужным дата аттрибутом, вставить в DOM, а потом найти его, если он есть?)

Comment: все можете. поиск только с селекторами не будет работать.  можете написать например `$("<xxx>").attr('data-tel', ...).appendTo("#list")` и должно заработать.

Comment: ан нет. в ответах нашли баг. но относительно написанного выше, аналогичная строка с использованием `data()` вместо `attr` не будет потом искаться через селекторы.

Comment: @teran Понял спасибо! Но я как раз и думал создавать через `attr`. Я просто забыл что есть `data()` и подумал, что очевидно как надо создавать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`li` в запросе убрать надо

```
$(".data-list").find(`[data-tel='${this.id}']`).remove();
```

Или еще короче сделать

```
$(`.data-list li[data-tel='${this.id}']`).remove();
```

Comment: или на filter заменить